# linq : update/delete junction table have two Primary Key

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

```
    public void Update (Rate a)
    {
           a = (from ee in DataContext.Rates
                where ee.users_Id == a.users_Id && ee.books_Id == a.books_Id
                        select ee).SingleOrDefault();

        DataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Rates'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Rates'. The duplicate key value is (3, 1).

Comment: So...you accept a `Rate` as a parameter. Then you overwrite the accepted Rate with the same Rate? And then you do nothing with it. What are you _trying_ to do?

Comment: You **cannot** have **two primary keys** on a relational table. But you *can have* a **single primary key** made up from two columns .....